# accessing menu from several subcategories

Tags: html, css, menu

Is there any other way to access one and the same menu without re-adding the code for it in each "page"?

I mean a menu looks exactly the same, no matter which part of the site you´re in. 
So there should be a way to have that menu attached to every page on the site without adding the code for every page you create?

Comment: What kind of site are you building? Plain jane HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which language you want to use for your site development?

There are lot of frameworks available for each language.

For example struts with tiles in java.

In tiles concept you will be defining some base layouts. which will specify header here sidebar here etc.

Then on next pages you can simply extend your new page into your base layout. There even if you are not specifying any content specifically, it will take previously defined one by default.

For example refer the  [struts tiles example link](http://www.vaannila.com/struts/struts-example/struts-tiles-example-1.html).

In jsp there is an option to add a page within an another page. Key word is

```
<%@ include file='menu.jsp'%>
```

here menu.jsp is mu menu bar, which I am calling to a location in my page. So hat it it will appear in the place where I specified. If you are not comfortable with tiles concept, you can use this method for adding menu into your pages with out repeating entire codes in all pages.

Answer (score 0):

There are a good number of ways to do this, and as far as I am concerned, they all use PHP or something similar to generate the HTML menu code on each individual page.

The browser must have all the content or it will not display a particular part. One can either hard code something like a menu into every html page or they could create something more of a php site which generates the html and serves it to the browser.

Other the writing the php yourself, off the shelf solutions will (often) allow you to do this. Examples would be shopping carts, as well as content management systems (CMS).